# Can something be "fully mitigated"?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

In my work I often see the term "fully mitigated". This does not seem correct to me. If mitigate means to reduce or lessen then can anything ever be fully mitigated? Would a more correct term be remediated?

Comment: Please provide more context. What line of work are you in? Please include some examples where you find it odd.

Comment: Sounds like legalese to me

Comment: *Fully mediated* is arguably closer to *eliminated* than *remediated*.

Comment: Fully mediated shows up on Google NGram, often in government documents.

Comment: Did you mean *remedied* rather than *remediated*?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, yes.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=mitigate

> 1. To make less severe or intense; moderate or **alleviate**. See Synonyms at **relieve**.

Fully mitigated, meaning fully alleviated (relieved), makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In everyday English, it would be indeed odd to say that something has been 'fully mitigated'. If the the work on reducing the undesirable impact of something is only partially successful, it is natural to call it mitigation; if it is completely successful (i.e. everything is as if nothing bad has happened), we would be more likely so use some other word, and to say, for example, that the problem has been remedied, or that that the damage has been eliminated, or that it has been repaired.

In legal contexts, however, *mitigation* sometimes functions as a technical term, and using that term connects the specific matter under discussion to a considerable body of the law. In order to make that connection, lawyers may use the term even when it would be otherwise unnatural, and so sometimes speak of full mitigation.